# PHP shel_exec not run in background

Tags: php, linux, shell, task

I found a lot of content on the web about run php code in the background, but I can not recreate the scenario in my machine.
Here my code:

```
//call.php
function run_background()
{
    $PID = shell_exec("nohup php teste.php &");
    return $PID;
}

function checking_process($pid)
{
    exec("ps $pid", $state);
    return (count($state) >= 2);
}

$ps = run_background();
copy("yel", "temp/yel2");
```

When you run the call.php file, the page is loading until the test.php file to run. This is the file for testing:

```
//test.php
for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++)
{
    sleep(1);
}
copy("yel", "temp/yel");
```

In both files I use the copy function to test the time when actions are performed. At this point I would expect that as the file test.php in this background and it takes at least 5 seconds, the flow of call.php file should independently occur, but 'yel2' file is only created after the 'yel' file.
However, the function is not actually running in the background, that error'm making?

Note: I'm using Manjaro Linux 64bits, PHP 5.5 and Apache 2.4

Note2: The $ PID returned from run_background function is valid, I can clearly find it with the command 'ps aux'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of just adding `&` at the end try adding `>& /dev/null &` this is what I have had success with. So would end up with something like this:

```
$PID = shell_exec("nohup php teste.php >& /dev/null &");
```

Comment: Oh, it works. I had already seen some examples with the addition of 'dev / null' but not this way. I also found out that what prevented the code work properly was the array of characters. In this example I found on the internet 'nohup teste.php 2> /dev/null & echo $!', just change the '2>' to '> 2' and the code runs as it should, i think this can influence something and shows that I study more shell script. Either way thank you very much, I found a cleaner and clear answer